# Problems logging into MacOS using Active Directory user not working, but SSH works fine

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, remote-desktop

I am having trouble with logging into our MacOS device in the office but I can SSH into the device and I can view the login screen via VNC.

What steps can I use to troubleshoot why I cannot log into the Mac as any user?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by deleting the user and creating a new user with the same name through the command line. I've no idea why the problem happened, but all other solutions didn't work.